# Access string-array resource programmatically and add value to it

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, arraylist

I have an empty string-array resource in my strings.xml file like below:

```
<string-array name="categories"/>
```

I'm getting array of data from an API back which I need to populate onto a listview. Its ArrayAdapter takes in an `@ArrayResource int` for its resource like below:

```
public void showListViewDialog(…, @ArrayRes int arrayResource) {

    ...

    ListView listView = alertDialogView.findViewById(R.id.listViewCategories);
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context,
            arrayResource, R.layout.custom_list_item);

    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

}
```

In my Java class, this is how I am retrieving the string-array resource:

```
List<String> categoriesToAdd= Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.categories));
```

How can I then add the data back to it? I've tried the following but it does not work:

```
List<String> listCategories = new ArrayList<>();
listCategories.add(categoriesToAdd);
```

Comment: do you want to change string resource at runtime?

Comment: Yes, dynamically as I fetch the content online

Comment: it is impossible to change resources at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to alter the string-array resource at run-time. So you cannot update it to show data in a `ListView`.

You don't need a string-array resource to create an `ArrayAdapter`. Instead, you can simply pass an `ArrayList` to its constructor to create it.

For example:

```
List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

// sample data
data.add("Data 1");
data.add("Data 2");

final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this /*context*/,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, data);

ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now if you want to add data to the list, use:

```
adapter.add("Data 3");
```

Answer (score 1):

AFIK, Its not possible to change any resource files at runtime which bundled in `APK`. What you can do, just fetch your data from API and use it and if you want to save it for later use then save it in `SharedPreferences` file